# Python regex to extract data from files with various structures

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a file with numerous lines from which I want to extract data. The structure is similar to this one

```
Detected 3 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n Very low Helium (1.5% total)\r\n Medium Oxygen (20% total)\r\n Low Nitrogen (6.5% total)\r\n
Detected 0 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n
Detected 2 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n Low Carbon monoxide (5% total)\r\n Very high Helium (80% total)\r\n Traces of Oxygen\r\n
Detected 1 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n Medium Nitrogen (18.5% total)\r\n Traces of Helium, Argon\r\n
```

I would like to extract data using regex to obtain a data array (ideally a pandas dataframe) similar to this

| Sample | Detected | Helium (txt) | Helium (%) | Oxygen (txt) | Oxygen (%) | Nitrogen (txt) | Nitrogen (%) | Carbon monoxide (txt) | Carbon monoxide (%) | Argon (txt) | Argon (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | Very low | 1.5 | Medium | 20 | Low | 6.5 | - | - | - | - |
| 1 | 0 | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| 2 | 2 | Very high | 80 | Traces | - | - | - | Low | 5 | - | - |
| 3 | 1 | Traces | - | - | - | Medium | 18.5 | - | - | Traces | - |

The first column is inherent to pandas dataframe. The second can be either extracted from the first sentence of each line or can be easily obtained by considering the number of gas for which the % composition is known (so the first sentence can be ignored).
The example I give sums up all the different lines structures :

- Gas compositions does not sum to 100% (due to undetected gas) and can
  be integers or floats,
- Gas names can be one or more words but always start with an upper case character,
- Gas proportions are characterized by a small text, "Very low" etc..., which can also be one or more words but always start with an upper case character,
- Gas that are detected but for which the composition is too low are listed at the end starting with "Traces of", and are not counted as "detected",
- Sometimes no gas are detected
- Gas detection are separated by newline characters `\r\n`

Moreover, the list of all possible detected gas is not know in advance when the file is opened, i.e, the columns have to be built from the data in the file.
I'm really starting to learn regex and this may be a little bit ambitious for a beginning.
What I'm trying to do is to translate in regex something like "Match all sequences starting with an upper case followed by any number of lower case characters OR sequences between `(` and `% total)`", which normally would give me (ignoring the first sentence of each line) something like `['Very low','Helium','1.5','Medium','Oxygen','20',...]`. But I really struggle to translate it into regex and even with the help of regex101.com I'm not sure to understand how things work.

I would be really happy to have some help and explanation of why your solution works.

Comment: What do you mean by _Gas detection are separated by newline characters `\r\n`_? The newline character is only `\n`, and this only if this sequence is translated to NL. So, do you have the 4-character sequence `\r\n` in your file, or the 2-character sequence CR NL? If the latter, the _structure_ you described in your post is inaccurate, since a data row then spans multiple lines, not just one as you described.

Comment: I have the 4-char sequence '\r\n' in my file, yes. In one version of my code I got rid of it when reading the file to avoid confusion but during the writing of this post I thought they might be useful to delimit the different parts of each line (It looks like RJ Adriaansen went with this strategy.), so I left them in, although I could have replaced them with standard separator characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach to using regular expressions with no static lists of gases / observation text

- simpler to parse text if each line is parsed.  There are two line structures

  1. sample header,  where **dectected** is extracted
  2. sample detail, contains **gas name**, **gas text** and **percentage**

```
import re

text = """Detected 3 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n Very low Helium (1.5% total)\r\n Medium Oxygen (20% total)\r\n Low Nitrogen (6.5% total)\r\n
Detected 0 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n
Detected 2 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n Low Carbon monoxide (5% total)\r\n Very high Helium (80% total)\r\n Traces of Oxygen\r\n
Detected 1 gas in sample. Composition :\r\n Medium Nitrogen (18.5% total)\r\n Traces of Helium, Argon\r\n"""

# keep all lines separate,  it's simpler to parse...
df = pd.DataFrame(re.split("\r\n\n?", text), columns=["text"]).replace("",np.nan).dropna()

# extract number of samples and assign a sample#
df = df.assign(main=df.text.str.contains("Detected"),
          sample=lambda dfa: dfa.main.cumsum(),
          detected=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.main, dfa.text.str.extract(r'([0-9])', expand=False), np.nan),
         ).fillna(method="ffill")

# extract the gas, gas text, gas %age from each of the samples
# where gases are comma-separated generate list and explode()
df2 = (df.join(df.text.str.extract(r'(?P<txt>[V,M,L,T][a-z, ]*)(?P<gas>[A-Z,a-z \,]*)\(?(?P<pct>\d*\.?\d*)'))
       .assign(gas=lambda dfa: dfa.gas.str.strip().str.split(", "))
       .explode("gas")
      ).rename(columns={"pct":"%"})


# reshape structure of samples and name columns
df2 = df2.loc[~df2.main, ["sample","gas","txt","%"]].set_index(["sample","gas"]).unstack(1)
df2.columns= [f"{tup[1]} ({tup[0]})" for tup in df2.columns]

# finally pull it all together
df.loc[df.main, ["sample","detected"]].merge(df2, on="sample", how="left").replace(np.nan, "")
```

#### output

|  | sample | detected | Argon (txt) | Carbon monoxide (txt) | Helium (txt) | Nitrogen (txt) | Oxygen (txt) | Argon (%) | Carbon monoxide (%) | Helium (%) | Nitrogen (%) | Oxygen (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |  |  | Very low | Low | Medium |  |  | 1.5 | 6.5 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |  | Low | Very high |  | Traces of |  | 5 | 80 |  |  |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | Traces of |  | Traces of | Medium |  |  |  |  | 18.5 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex solution (but it relies on the in-string newline characters being saved as strings in the file, see Armanli's comment). There is no need for regex as the strings have a similar structure. This solution loops the lines in the file, split on `\\r\\n`, and extracts `Detected`, `Traces` or any of the gasses from the list. It saves the values in a list of dicts which can be loaded into pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

gasses = ['Helium', 'Oxygen', 'Nitrogen', 'Carbon monoxide', 'Argon']
def get_data(gas, line):
    return [line.split(f' {gas} (')[0].strip(), float(line.split(f' {gas} (')[1].split('%')[0])]    

all_data = []
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    d = [i.split('\\r\\n') for i in f.readlines()]
    for i in d:
        tmp_dict = {}
        for z in i[:-1]:
            if 'Detected' in z:
                tmp_dict['Detected'] = int(z.split(" ")[1])
            elif 'Traces' in z:
                tr = z[10:].split(', ')
                for t in tr:
                    tmp_dict[f'{t.strip()} (txt)'] = 'Traces'
            else:
                gas = [ele for ele in gasses if(ele in z)] [0]
                r = get_data(gas, z)
                tmp_dict[f'{gas} (txt)'] = r[0]
                tmp_dict[f'{gas} (%)'] = r[1]               
        all_data.append(tmp_dict)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
```

Output:

|  | Detected | Helium (txt) | Helium (%) | Oxygen (txt) | Oxygen (%) | Nitrogen (txt) | Nitrogen (%) | Carbon monoxide (txt) | Carbon monoxide (%) | Argon (txt) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | Very low | 1.5 | Medium | 20 | Low | 6.5 | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 2 | Very high | 80 | Traces | nan | nan | nan | Low | 5 | nan |
| 3 | 1 | Traces | nan | nan | nan | Medium | 18.5 | nan | nan | Traces |